# How to drop duplicate from DataFrame taking into account value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I drop `John` as duplicate specifying 'name' as the column name:

```
import pandas as pd   
data = {'name':['Bill','Steve','John','John','John'], 'age':[21,28,22,30,29]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.drop_duplicates('name')
```

pandas drops all matching entities leaving the left-most:

```
   age   name
0   21   Bill
1   28  Steve
2   22   John
```

Instead I would like to keep the row where John's age is the highest (in this example it is the age 30. How to achieve this?

Comment: try this: `df.drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')` or `df.sort_values('age').drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [75]: df
Out[75]:
   age   name
0   21   Bill
1   28  Steve
2   22   John
3   30   John
4   29   John

In [76]: df.sort_values('age').drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')
Out[76]:
   age   name
0   21   Bill
1   28  Steve
3   30   John
```

or this depending on your goals:

```
In [77]: df.drop_duplicates('name', keep='last')
Out[77]:
   age   name
0   21   Bill
1   28  Steve
4   29   John
```

Comment: Great! Sorting would be a solution here with `keep` flat set to last. Thanks!